# ¿Cómo saber si mi comentario puede ser una respuesta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, comentarios

Llevo poquito tiempo en SOes y las veces que he respondido a una pregunta me ha surgido esta duda. Hay veces que hay preguntas cuya respuesta es sencilla y concisa y no da pie a desarrollar nada o, intentando aclarar una duda antes de contestar, acabas contestando en un comentario.

Un ejemplo es [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158318/aviso-de-cookies-si-solo-uso-la-cookie-de-sesi%C3%B3n-de-php). El primer comentario ha sido la respuesta tal cual pero, al ser sencillamente decir "no, aquí puedes mirar por qué" se ha puesto como un comentario (doy por hecho que ha sido así porque a mí me ha pasado).

Normalmente si, por ejemplo, en una pregunta en la que ponen un código y no se sabe por qué falla, al ver la ausencia de un punto y coma lo añades como comentario ("en tal línea no tienes punto y coma"). Si  tras ello el código funcionara ¿estaría correcto añadirlo como respuesta o debería mantenerse como comentario?

A lo mejor es una pregunta estúpida pero no es la primera vez que dudo si hacer una respuesta o comentario...

Comment: En el ejemplo que enlazas, en realidad era una respuesta que yo convertí a comentario. ¿Por qué? Vi que era un usuario nuevo (no ha hecho el tour aun) y por tener menos de 50 de reputación no puede publicar comentarios salvo en sus propias publicaciones (o en respuestas a sus preguntas) por lo que en la gran mayoria de los casos publican respuestas donde querrían haber puesto un comentario. Además, no lo considero una respuesta de calidad porque solo es un enlace y no la informacion en la propia publicación como hizo Dan Novek. Un saludo

Comment: Vale, no sabía que había sido una respuesta primero, entiendo a lo que te refieres y ya puedo hacerme mejor idea de cómo funciona el sitio, es bastante sencillo pero siempre hay cositas que a los usuarios despistados nos lían. ¡Gracias por responder tan rápido! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para empezar, ninguna pregunta es estupida, siempre es bueno preguntar lo que no se sabe :)

Por un lado, analizamos la pregunta que pones como ejemplo. En este caso, hay un comentario y una respuesta. Normalmente (yo también lo suelo hacer), si tu respuesta es básicamente un enlace y *aquí puedes consultar la solución*, el sitio adecuado es el comentario (como es el caso de tu ejemplo).

Luego existe una respuesta, mas extensa, en la que además de los enlaces copia las partes relevantes de ellos, haciendo que sea una respuesta completa que aún en el caso de que los enlaces desaparezcan, seguirá teniendo sentido.

Así que la pregunta que enlazas es un buen ejemplo de como se debe actuar.

(Edito: veo que nuestro moderador @lois6b convirtió una respuesta a comentario. Como explica, una respuesta que es básicamente un enlace a un sitio externo no puede ser nunca una respuesta, ya que si el enlace deja de existir la respuesta pierde toda su utilidad)

> Normalmente si, por ejemplo, en una pregunta en la que ponen un código y no se sabe por qué falla, al ver la ausencia de un punto y coma lo añades como comentario ("en tal línea no tienes punto y coma"). Si tras ello el código funcionara ¿estaría correcto añadirlo como respuesta o debería mantenerse como comentario?

En este caso no, no se debe añadir como respuesta ya que un error tipográfico es causa de cierre de la pregunta.

Otro caso sería que no estés muy seguro de que tu respuesta sea correcta para el OP. En ese caso, puedes añadir un comentario y si el OP confirma que ha solucionado su problema, puedes plantearte añadir tu comentario como respuesta, a ser posible extendiéndola con cuantos mas datos mejor.

Para finalizar, es normal a veces dudar si una pregunta merece una respuesta o no, y no hay una norma estricta. Es bueno leer el centro de Ayuda y concretamente [Cómo Responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), y como ahí se dice:

> Contesta preguntas bien formadas
>
> No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que…
>
> ... son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real.
>
> ... solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades.
>
> ... ya se han preguntado antes y se han contestado varias veces.
>
> ... requieren demasiada orientación para que puedas contestarla completamente.
>
> ... no tratan sobre la programación o el desarrollo como lo definimos en el Centro de ayuda.

Y en cuanto a los enlaces:

> Ofrece contexto para los enlaces
>
> Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudará a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porqué decidiste añadirlos. Procura siempre citar la parte más relevante del enlace por si la página web desaparece o es cambiada en un futuro.

Comment: Sin duda me ha quedado todo muchísimo más claro. Lo has explicado perfecto y me hago una idea de cuándo hacer una cosa u otra ¡Muchas gracias! :)

Comment: Me alegro de habértelo aclarado @Rabegi. Y lo que no he dicho, pero ante cualquier duda, no dudes de preguntar en meta o en [chat]. Un saludo

Comment: Justo me planteaba realizar la misma pregunta que Rabegi, Gracias @Pikoh