# ¿Qué debemos hacer con las recomendaciones que mandan a leer una respuesta en inglés?

Tags: discusión, idiomas

Últimamente estoy notando un nuevo "defecto" en el sitio, y es contestar a las preguntas en comentarios, mandando a leer una respuesta del sitio en inglés.

Más allá que puede ser que OP no la haya encontrado o algún otro motivo, lo que me preocupa principalmente es que estando en el sitio en español, la respuesta no debería ser ve a ver la respuesta del sitio en inglés.

Si esa fuera la respuesta, ¿no hubiera sido más lógico que quien preguntara fuera a preguntar directamente en el sitio en inglés?

Yo propongo que en estos casos, le dejemos un comentario a quién comenta con algún tipo de respuesta estándar, donde se le aclare a quien comenta que la finalidad del sitio es dar respuestas y no mandarlos a leer en inglés.

¡Ah!, como si fuera poco, nadie sabe si el OP sabe inglés.

El comentario que propongo sería algo así:

> @persona Gracias por el enlace al sitio en inglés, sin embargo sería ideal que si eso contesta la pregunta, agregaras una respuesta en español, y aclares que sacaste la idea de la respuesta en ingles. No sabemos si OP sabe inglés y tal vez el link no le sirva.

Comment: En toda la medida siempre es mejor que los enlaces sean al sitio en español, en caso de que tal enlace no exista, pienso que _lo correcto_ seria traducir la respuesta que encontraste y adaptarla al caso que se pregunta; los enlaces al sitio en ingles no deben ser más que una "lectura recomendada", incluso si es la respuesta al problema que se plantea.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, si uno hace una pregunta en el sitio de español es por que evidentemente espera una respuesta en español, pueden ser muchas razones por la cual la pregunta fue hecha en español y una de ellas es que el OP no sepa inglés, entonces de nada serviría redirigirlo a otro sitio, además sería bueno remarcar esto en el [help] para que esté a la lectura de todos :)

Comment: ¿Y si le decimos que realize una traducción en esa respuesta colocando como referencia el enlace al sitio en inglés? ¿O que traduzca y corte esta referencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que comentas es muy común Gonzalo, no todos los desarrolladores aún menos los que inician (lo comento por experiencia), pudieran entender la información en idioma inglés (u otro idioma), he notado que para algunos usuarios les parece obvio (ya que los lenguajes de programación están basados en el idioma inglés), pero en realidad esto no es así.

Debemos tener la información en español, para esto precisamente se creo https://es.stackoverflow.com , para tener una base de datos con información en idioma español.

Si deseamos en realidad ayudar a los usuarios del sitio, agregar un enlace en otro idioma puede no ser siempre la forma adecuada:

[**Как сравнивать строки в Java?**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417405/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java)

[**@Statelessと@RequestScopedの用途の違い**](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29246/stateless%E3%81%A8requestscoped%E3%81%AE%E7%94%A8%E9%80%94%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84)

[**mongoError: Topology was destroyed**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909492/mongoerror-topology-was-destroyed)

Como comentas lo ideal sería sugerir a los usuarios que agregan estos comentarios nos ayuden a traducir la información del enlace que sugieren del sitio en inglés, incluso como comenta @NaCl adaptarla a la pregunta en cuestión, agregando la fuente y atribuir el crédito a quien realizo originalmente la respuesta. 
Esta tarea también la podríamos realizar alguno de nosotros como miembros de la comunidad.

---

Recuerdo la respuesta de un usuario de la comunidad a un comentario :

> "ese enlace ya lo ví pero esta en inglés, no se supone que aquí se
>   puede preguntar en español, por eso pregunte aquí"

**En un futuro muchos usuarios que inician en el mundo del desarrollo de software seguramente no tendrán problema en leer información en otro idioma, mientras tanto hay que ser pacientes y apoyarlos brindándoles ayuda en español, esa fue una de las razones por las cuales fue creado [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com).**

Answer (score 10):

No estoy muy de acuerdo contigo Gonzalo. Un comentario es eso, un comentario, no una respuesta. Es una indicación de donde podría encontrar la respuesta a su pregunta o al menos un punto de partida.

Si el OP no sabe inglés, hay sistemas muy sencillos de traducción, aunque normalmente cuando yo enlazo a alguna respuesta en inglés(algo que hago comunmente) suelen ser respuestas en las que lo importante es el código, con lo que el idioma no debe ser ningún impedimento.

Además, debemos tener en cuenta que un porcentaje muy elevado de información se encuentra en inglés. Claro que lo ideal sería poder encontrar todo en español, pero creo que es imposible hoy por hoy, con lo que aunque no se sepa el idioma, es necesario saber extraer lo que necesitas de un texto en ingles.

Por último, el que comenta en estos casos puede tener sus razones para enlazar en lugar de responder (a lo mejor tampoco sabe inglés pero el código sabe que ayudará al OP, o simplemente no le apetece ponerse a traducir). No veo porqué razón habría que poner trabas a esto. El efecto que puede conseguirse con ello es que este tipo de comentarios desaparezca y que alguien que podría recibir ayuda (aunque tuviera que hacer el esfuerzo de traducirla) se quede sin ella.

Comment: Coincido contigo que si el OP no sabe inglés podría usar una herramienta de traducción, que cuando lo importante es el código podría no ser importante el idioma de la publicación. En lo que no coincido es en el entendimiento de que Gonzalo esté proponiendo poner trabas, tal sólo está proponiendo una forma de promover ir más allá de dejar un enlace a una publicación en inglés.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices @Rubén, pero para promover que se añada una respuesta aunque sea una traducción del original no veo necesario llegar a ningun acuerdo aquí en meta. [Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190909/contar-n%c3%bamero-de-elementos-en-un-string-separados-por-en-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment357991_190909) hay un ejemplo de un comentario de gonzalo hacía mi que me parece que es perfecto (y que es posible que haya provocado este post) :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo, no es necesario para que podamos usar SOes. Sin embargo no está mal pedir puntos de vista, para eso está [meta-tag:discusión] en particular cuando se trata de usar de la mejor forma las características del sitio con la finalidad de enriquecer la participación.

Comment: @Pikoh Estoy completamente de acuerdo contigo, si el usuario no sabe inglés, hay muchos métodos de traducción y como aclaras lo más importante es el código en si por lo tanto eso no sería un problema. +1

Answer (score 1):

Los **comentarios** son menos rígidos que las **respuestas**, *un comentario no es una respuesta*, asi que para mi no hay incoveniente que suceda eso en los comentarios. He visto muchas preguntas sin respuestas porque probablemente no tengamos expertos en ese tema dentro de la comunidad, asi que un enlace a cualquier blog, sitio en otro idioma, la documentación en cualquier idioma quizas ayuda o quizas no. ¿qué perdemos si se siguien usando?

Otra cosa fuese si se hace en la sección de **respuestas**, en ella sería válida si la respuesta no depende directamente del enlace, es decir aun si se elimina el enlace la respuesta deberia seguir siendo util. Porque los enlaces externos sirven para reforzar, no para fundamentar la respuesta.

Ovbiamente como señala [@NaCl](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4499/nacl) en los comentarios, se debe dar preferencias a los enlaces en español.

Por último muchas veces he dado como respuesta un resumen de las mejores respuestas que se dan al sitio en inglés obviamente señalando la fuente.

---

Parece que la razon que tiene [@gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) para la pregunta es evitar que los comentarios sustituyan a una respuesta, es decir, parece que cuando alguien coloca un enlace al sitio en inglés los usuarios que podrian responder no lo hacen, y para mi no hay relación de causalidad en ambos hechos. En varias preguntas donde publique una respuesta habian en la sección de comentarios enlaces a otros sitios, y aun asi publique mi respuesta, muchas veces usando como referencia a los enlaces externos, porque para mi un enlace a SOen es similar a cualquier otro enlace, si aporta lo coloco si no, lo descarto.

---

En resumen:

- Los comentarios no necesariamente tienen que se rigurosos, por lo que en general se podria publicar un enlace a cualquier recurso externo en cualquier idioma.
- Los enlaces externos en una respuesta solo sirven de respaldo, si una respuesta contiene solo un enlace sin explicación deberia ser eliminado por la comunidad porque no es una respuesta de calidad.
- Pienso que se esta echando la culpa a los comentarios que señalan al sitio en inglés innecesariamente, el problema principal es la no publicación de respuestas, deberiamos centrarnos en pensar en propuestas para que cambie ello.

Comment: Y que te asegura que op sabe ingles? Y como sabes si el proximo que vea la pregunta va a entender ingles? Si es asi, que sentido tiene hacer la pregunta en español. No pensas que es mejor tener la respuesta en español?

Comment: @gbianchi los comentarios son comentarios, si el OP sabe inglés lo usara, y si no, no lo usará, es sencillo, en una respuesta en cambio debe haber más rigurosidad.

Comment: @gbianchi como señale se debe preferir enlaces es español pero existen muy buenas respuestas en el sitio en inglés que muchas profundizan, asi que no veo negativo señalarlos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo.  Aunque la persona no sepa ingles, de todas formas el enlace le va a ayudar.  Como todos sabemos, todos los lenguajes de programacion estan basados en el ingles, por lo que un enlace al sitio en ingles puede ser de mucha ayuda.  Talvez es una pregunta sencilla que no amerita una respuesta completa.  Si este fuera un sitio de literatura en español y pusieramos enlaces a sitios en ingles seria diferente.

Comment: @alanfcm mi concepción de comentario es que solo es un texto de ayuda, no es una respuesta necesariamente, por lo que en ese texto de ayuda se pueden colocar enlaces de cualquier idioma que pueden ayudar, si el OP no sabe el idioma no lo usara simplemente, en cambio otros usuarios lo podrian traducir, leer, aprender de ese enlace y proponer una respuesta, todos ganamos. En cambio si la respuesta fuese solo el enlace entonces de por si es una mala respuesta ya que una respuesta de calidad no debe basarse en solo un enlace, deberia ser eliminado por la comunidad.

Comment: De acuerdo, hay muchas preguntas que no reciben ni una sola respuesta.  Quizas ese enlace sea la unica ayuda que el usuario reciba.  Quizas yo no tenga tiempo de dar una respuesta completa, pero por lo menos lo guio a un recurso que lo puede ayudar.

Comment: @alanfcm exacto, y en SOes donde escasea muchas veces la ayuda en ciertos temas en donde ni siquiere se comenta y menos se responde es una buena opción.

Comment: Y que me dices de la documentacion.  Muchas tecnologias, sobre todo las mas modernas, no poseen documentacion en español.  Eso quiere decir que no podemos guiarlos a la documentacion en ingles?

Comment: Justamente lo que señalo es lo contrario. Dejar el comentario provoca que nadie responda porque esta respondida en el comentario. No digo que no se ponga el enlace. Pero es mucho mejor traducir la respuesta al español. Si no, que sentido tiene tener un sitio en español? Hagamos todo en ingles y listo. Hablo de coherencia en el idioma que se usa en el sitio.

Comment: @alanfcm jajaja, es como dispararse en los pies. :)

Comment: @gbianchi no se responde porque no se quiere o no se puede, no por el enlace. No se puede porque quizas no tengamos todos los expertos en todos los temas, somos muy pocos los que respondemos y probablemente no en conjunto no podriamos satisfacer las necesidades de los que preguntan. O no queramos porque no tenemos el tiempo, o veamos irrelevante la pregunta, etc. Si tu intención con la preguntar es alentar las respuestas creo que estas yendo por un camino equivocado, como señalo en mi respuesta los enlaces externos siempre deben ser de respaldo, no la parte fundamental de la respuesta.

Comment: Ya tradujimos muchas respuestas existentes en ingles. Y a eso apunto. La respuesta puede ser hasta una copia fiel (respetando el link a la original), pero debe estar en español.

Comment: @gbianchi Te comento algo, siempre que respondo trato de guiar al usuario a otros post, pero desgraciadamente si uno hace una búsqueda en google no salen muchas respuestas del sitio en español, quizas porque los titulos no son genéricos, o porque no tienen muchas vistas.

Comment: @eyllanesc o tal vez no saben buscar ;) https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=site%3Aes.stackoverflow.com+inyecci%C3%B3n+sql

Comment: @KacosPro ya ves, difundir el uso de `site:es.stackoverflow.com` podria ayudarnos a promover a respaldar nuestras respuestas en español con enlaces en español. :), aun asi en mis respuestas seguire señalando enlaces a los sitios externo que fuese escrito en el idioma español o no, fuese SOen o no. los enlaces sirven de respaldo, y los que solo se limitan a no responder porque alguien no publico una comentario al sitio en inglés pues no se limitan, respondan :)

Comment: @gbianchi "Dejar el comentario provoca que nadie responda porque esta respondida en el comentario." eso es mas un "no voy a responder porque no me van a aceptar ni dar puntos", lo mas constructivo sería avisar a quienes ven la pregunta que pueden dar una respuesta. Quien dejó el enlace tiene sus razones para no dar una respuesta (falta de tiempo, detalles, contexto). El gran problema me parece que es que teniendo todas las fuentes (inglés o chino) nadie responda por que lo considera una perdida de tiempo.

Comment: @aloMalbarez pero no es justamente lo que puse en la pregunta? dejar un comentario para que se responda en lugar de mandar a revisar un link en otro idioma?

Comment: @gbianchi nope, dejar el comentario no te asegura que haya una respuesta. si la idea es que no haya ni enlaces ni respuestas es otra cosa. pero repito una pregunta con la "respuesta" servida en un comentario y 60 visitas que no generan una respuesta en mi opinión es un poco mas grave

Comment: no te sigo @aloMalbarez.. y si no cual es la idea? por lo menos con el comentario ya hacemos algo...

Comment: Como chiste fácil iba a deja un enlace en los comentarios =P . pongo una respuesta a ver si se aclara un poco el por qué no creo que vaya por ese lado la falta de respuestas y que un enlace no invalida una respuesta

Comment: @gbianchi la parte que a mi no me gusta de tu post es: *la respuesta no deberia ser ve a ver la respuesta del sitio en ingles.*, estas asumiendo que un comentario es una respuesta, y no lo es. El comentario que señalas: *@persona Gracias por el enlace ...* lo podria hacer cualquier, no hay necesidad de normar ello.

Comment: @eyllanesc lo asumo porque en esos casos, en casi el 100%, no hay respuesta despues de esos comentarios.. y siempre se le dice, ve a fijarte aca.. o aca ya esta contestado, o esto te puede servir... y no lo sabemos...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿y has pensado por qué no se propuso una respuesta? quizas el que comento no conoce el tema, y la ayuda que puede proponer es solo el enlace ¿estamos atacando el tema de fondo?, el tema de fondo para mi es: **somos muy pocos los que respondemos.**

Comment: justamente, por eso, digo de dejar un comentario! no puedo obligar a quien dejo el comentario a que traduzca, pero por lo menos puedo tratar de hacerle entender el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo el punto que señalas pero con tu post estas señalando que los enlaces externos de por si son incorrectos ya que estan en otro idioma, y eso no es correcto, en ninguno de las reglas de SOes señala eso, si tu post fuese en el sentido que mejor es que se use el español, pero que enlaces a otros idiomas tambien son buenos, pero debe preferirse si se puede el español.

Comment: Nunca dije que estuviera prohibido. Digo que si dejamos enlaces en otros idiomas, estamos suponiendo que OP sabe otro idioma, y que ademas no dejamos base para futuros usuarios, que por ahi no sepan ese otro idioma.

Answer (score 1):

Qué debemos hacer?

1. Nada: el sitio es para resolver problemas si la solución está en los comentarios es irrelevante es sólo una cuestión de formato. Si sirve la gente vuelve, se ven las publicidades, se pagan las cuentas y se corre la bola, mas usuarios, mas participación y con el tiempo menos casos como estos (relacionado a punto 3).
2. Primerearlo: leer la pregunta, seguir el enlace, si está en contexto usar el enlace para crear una respuesta. El que preguntó puede que esté conforme con un enlace, quien visite la pregunta en un par de meses o años **seguramente vaya a la respuesta formal** antes de seguir un enlace en los comentarios.
3. Reciclar la pregunta: luego de un tiempo se relanza a la página principal

> **Relanzada a la página principal** por Comunidad♦ hace 21 minutos
>
> Esta pregunta parece tener respuestas en forma de enlaces en los comentarios; ayúdanos a mejorar el sitio escribiendo una respuesta mas detallada.

Nuevo badge "OCD warrior" primera respuesta a una pregunta que sólo contiene comentarios y citando el/los enlaces en los comentarios. (no duplicada, no cerrada, etc...) se otorga al alcanzar los 5 votos positivos. (aunque nunca jamás se acepte como respuesta el voto popular asegura que está en concordancia con el/los enlaces)

nota: El nombre del badge propuesto es humorístico, puede ser algo relacionado a la alquimia o la transmutación (de comentario a respuesta)

Comment: mmm.. pero estamos hablando de enlances a paginas en otro idioma...

Comment: mas puntos para el que responda en español

Comment: no no.. si contestas en un comentario en español no es problema.. el problema es redirigir a una pagina en otro idioma...

Comment: no puedo hablar por otros, en mi caso si dejo un enlace es por que es lo mejor que puedo ofrecer en el momento. español va como prioridad e inglés (como lingua franca) va segundo. aunque hay traducciones en español que son muy confusas o cometen errores conceptuales ahi prefiero dejar un enlace al inglés.

Comment: y como sabes que el usuario sabe ingles?

Comment: no lo sé, pero es materia obligada o electiva en la mayoría de las tecnicaturas, licenciaturas e ingenierías relacionadas a este campo. hay mas chances de que encuentre una solución que si no hay ni enlace ni respuesta. (ver punto 1). encuentra solución toma el sitio como referente

Comment: Hay algo importante, que ni tu ni la otra respuesta estan teniendo en cuenta, y es que siempre se dice que para ayudar hay que tomarse el tiempo. Si no tenes tiempo para ayudar, no ayudes, alguien podra tomarse el tiempo en ayudar. Es lo mismo que para moderar, hay que tener tiempo y tomarselo. Nadie obliga a nadie a contestar ni con velocidad ni con prontitud. Solo se pide que haya respuestas claras, y en el idioma del sitio..

Comment: en mi caso todo el tiempo que tengo es usar mi google-fu para tirar una punta, si otra persona expande la respuesta mejor todavía. en mi experiencia prefiero un enlace en ruso (y que el código hable por si mismo) a no encontrar respuesta. no creo que limitar las opciones mejore nada (es mi opinión). si creo que se puede usar la oportunidad para que `otros` usuarios generen una respuesta

Comment: igual, no entiendo la discusion, ni de esta respuesta ni de la otra. Yo digo que me parece que eso podria ser un problema, y que tratemos de buscar alguna solucion (ni prohibir, ni retar, ni moderar ni nada).. entonces... vos decis que no es un problema.. ok.. no hagas nada y listo.. no entiendo realmente.. no estoy retando a nadie... ni protestando nada.. estoy haciendo notar algo que pasa...

Comment: el punto es que no lo veo como un problema a que haya enlaces a otros sitios en otros idiomas, si creo que es un indicador de que la gamificación podría ajustarse un poco para aprovechar estos casos y que si los enlaces son válidos se generen respuestas.

Comment: ok perfecto. a mi me da miedo que eso genere que no se responda porque ya esta el enlace en otro idioma.

Comment: ese es el síntoma, creo que el problema real es que no hay respuesta luego del enlace. y me da la sensación de que poner el foco mencionando al que puso el enlace da una excusa válida al resto de 60 visitas para no jugarse en dar una respuesta (no sólo parece respondida, también parece que le toca al que puso el enlace)

Comment: La idea de **Transmutación de los comentarios** me parece excelente. Muchísimas veces he encontrado en ellos **respuesta** a preguntas que aún no he formulado, cuando recorro preguntas similares a las que deseo plantear, para establecer si tiene o no sentido publicarlas. Esos enlaces, de ampliación, suelen ser aportes valiosos (con independencia del idioma). **Debiera crearse un mecanismo para destacarlos**.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

Lo de la respuesta estándar me parece bien, pero en lugar de hacer referencia al OP, opino que debería mencionarse que el idioma del sitio es español pues no se trata sólo de publicar algo que sólo le sirva al OP, sino que de formar una **base de de conocimiento en español**

## Respuesta extendida

Estamos de acuerdo en que independientemente del idioma del enlace en el comentario, un comentario no es una respuesta.

Supongamos que quien dejó el enlace fue su forma de dejar su "granito de arena". No veo nada malo en ello, sin embargo, la forma de agradecer es mediante reputación y esa sólo se gana mediante votos en preguntas y respuestas.

Si el autor del comentario no "regresa"...

Si ya existe una buena respuesta que incluye el enlace a la misma fuente o una equivalente opino que lo reportemos como **Ya no es necesario**.

Si aún no existe una buena respuesta consideremos una, la otra o ambas:

1. Como ya se mencionó, sugerir al autor del comentario que escriba una buena respuesta.
2. Publicar una respuesta

Relacionado

- [¿Qué hacer cuando me encuentro una solución en comentarios y el OP responde su propia pregunta pero no la marca como aceptada?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2816/65)
- [¿Cómo saber si mi comentario puede ser una respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3432/65)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con tu punto de vista(+1), pero te señalo el siguiente escenario: yo personalmente veo muchas preguntas no respondidas que son de buenas en la forma(no dire en el fondo) pero no son respondidas y yo no soy experto en el tema(justo por ello no califico el fondo) asi que mi granito de arena es dar un enlace a un recurso externo que en general puede estar en cualquier idioma y no espero recibir reputación, ¿sería malo publicar el enlace en la sección de comentarios?,

Comment: [cont]  mi intención es no desalentar la publicación de posibles respuestas sino ayudar al OP, y si le sirve al OP, él podria publicar su propia respuesta, y si no, sencillamente lo marcan como no necesario. Y el escenario anterior pasa muy a menudo.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Ya lo dije en mi respuesta, no veo nada de malo dejar un enlace (a una publicación pertinente / que no sea spam). No importa si el enlace es una publicación en español, inglés, japonés, ruso, esperanto, klingon o cualquier otro idioma, particularmente si este es soportado por alguna herramienta de traducción como Google Translate. Punto y aparte está el hecho de que la gran mayoría de los comentarios deberán ser eliminados en un plazo "de 6 a 8 semanas". Para los que no lo saben "6 a 8 semanas" es un meme de [se], se refiere a "algún día".