# ¿Qué se debe hacer con una respuesta en inglés publicada por alguien que parece representar a la herramienta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, traducciones-de-contenido

En la pregunta [URL modificada al ejecutarse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/417916/324) sobre un IDE tenemos esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/418343/324 en inglés. <strike>Obviamente al ver el perfil, notamos que es una fuente oficial al respecto.</strike>. Parecería ser que el autor de la pregunta es una fuente que trabaja en esta herramienta.

En mi punto de vista, deberíamos traducir la respuesta, pero tampoco quiero que al traducirla cometamos un error y por eso deje de ser <strike>oficial</strike> de alguien que parece que trabaja ahi...

OP parece no querer traducir la respuesta, y dejarla solamente en inglés en mi parecer es un NO.

¿Qué se debería hacer?

Comment: Ambas opciones. La oficial sin traducir, y agregado debajo la traducción hecha por X persona. Así no se deslegitima la respuesta, y se da traducción a español.

Comment: Nota: Tú dices: *Obviamente al ver el perfil, notamos que es una fuente oficial al respecto*, no estoy seguro de ello ya que cualquier puede colocar que pertenece a cierta compañia pero no implica que eso sea verdad

Comment: @eyllanesc miraste sus respuestas en ingles? si no trabaja ahi, lo esconde muy bien ;)

Comment: @gbianchi yo no dije eso, pero no asumas algo que el mismo OP no señala. Generalmente los desarrolladores que pertenecen a la compañia que desarrollan la tecnologia dan un disclaimer especificando con son parte del soporte oficial de la compañia

Comment: Si quieres estar seguro, puedes hacer contacto y verificarlo. Sería el de Rusia según su descripcion. -> https://www.jetbrains.com/company/contacts/#headquarters-international-sales

Comment: Por fuente oficial, no me refiero a que trabaje ahi.. es mas.. nunca dije que trabaja ahi.. lo que dije es que es alguien que responde todos esos tipos de preguntas, con links y documentacion referida a la aplicacion. inclusive mostrando tickets de soporte respecto de los problemas en las preguntas....

Comment: @gbianchi Yo respondo mis preguntas de Qt usando la documentación oficlal y otros recursos similares(tambien oficiales) pero no soy una *fuente oficial* de Qt. En general es lo recomendable ya que asi cualquier puede entender o refutar mejor el post

Comment: No es el punto de la discusion... y te das cuenta cuando es alguien que sabe, o alguien que trabaja ahi... pero en fin... no es el punto de la discusion... si te parece que la respuesta no va, tambien puedes pedir que la borren.. por eso levante esta discusion en meta....

Comment: Por otro lado no quiero distraer sobre un tema secundario(mi idea era que seas más preciso en tu afirmación), aun asi fuese una fuente ofical o certificada de la compañia no implica que no cumpla con las reglas del sitio, estamos en el SOes donde las preguntas y respuestas deben estar en el idioma españoĺ, caso contrario son inutiles

Comment: y ese es el punto.. vamos a rechazar una fuente oficial (o un dios de un lenguaje) porque no sabe español? es para ver como manejamos eso...

Comment: Para mi no hay dioses, lo minimo que se pide es que cumplan las reglas básicas del sitio, no le des más poder a nadie..., existen muchos recursos como google translate o servicio similares para que el traduzca su respuesta y cumpla con las reglas

Comment: Ademas no creo que ese usuario sea un dios o una fuente oficial, segun veo tiene una reputación promedio y existen  muchos más usuarios con mas puntaje en esos tags en SOen

Comment: @eyllanesc ahi esta mejor? a veces siento que le dan mas pelota a la semantica que a la cuestion de fondo... si no estas de acuerdo con que la respuesta sea en ingles, por favor aclaralo aca y listo....

Comment: @gbianchi Creo que debes saber que en [meta] la semántica es muy importante por lo que por favor tomalo en cuenta en tus posts

Comment: Valga decir que este usuario a mí me ha respondido alguna pregunta sobre Intellij IDEA, siempre de forma impecable. Creo un éxito que también mire preguntas en [es.so], que deberíamos alegrarnos de ello y que sería bueno hablarlo con ella de manera que le entren ganas de seguir haciéndolo.

Comment: Que el autor de la respuesta diga que solo puede estar correcto en ingles a mi solo me deja desconcertado, ¿Sólo en inglés está bien? ¿El castellano es erroneo siempre? ¿Y si fuera en árabe, chino, ruso u otro idioma también estaría mal? en mi opinión puede ser un tema racista, imponer el inglés y mas en un lugar con otro idioma establecido.

Comment: @NicolasOñate No dice eso, dice que si prefieren una respuesta mala en español, lo que lleva a deducir que EL no sabe español y no confía en google traductor para hacer la traducción el mismo. Por eso se niega a traducirla.

Comment: No entiendo porque se preocupan por esto, si un usuario hace una pregunta y otro usuario la contesta deberia contestarla con las reglas del sitio asi de simple, no deberia importar si es oficial o no, yo podria ser el mismo gerente general de jetbrains pero aun asi soy un usuario del sitio y por ende se debe respetar las reglas

Comment: Por que valoramos la respuesta por sobre el usuario, deberíamos traducirla, ponerla en otra respuesta, y reportar el usuario por romper la norma. No perdamos la respuesta y ya.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo que es una situación parecida a lo que pasa cuando un empleado de Stack Overflow pone una respuesta en inglés (con la diferencia de que ellos no tienen problema con que la comunidad traduzca su contenido).

Por un lado es genial tener las respuestas correctas en el sitio, eso es súper valioso. Por el otro, la idea de tener un sitio en nuestro idioma es que la gente no tenga que saber inglés para sacar provecho.

Por lo que me parece que podemos hacer algo así y que puede dejar a todos satisfechos:

1. Dejemos el texto original TAL CUAL el autor lo escribió
2. Pongamos abajo una traducción hecha por la comunidad, con un texto que explique la situación (le comentaría la idea al autor original, como para no vandalizar su publicación).

De esa forma, siempre tenemos la respuesta real, la gente que maneja los dos idiomas puede traducirla (y verificar que la traducción no pierda contenido) y quienes manejan sólo español puedan acceder al contenido.

Comment: Entonces cualquier usuario que conteste en cualquier idioma se mantendrá su respuesta y será traducido?

Comment: Si la comunidad entiende que el contenido es de calidad y quiere que quede en el sitio si, si no se eliminará la respuesta :) esto no intenta ser una regla, sino una sugerencia ;)

Comment: Una cosa no tengo en claro, ¿Quién es la comunidad? O como sabemos que todos quieren eso, yo puedo decir si, otro no y asi sucesivamente. O todos los que participaron en esta pregunta son la comunidad?

Comment: somos todos :) si dada una respuesta en particular (como esta) hay gente que la identifique como de calidad y alguien que quiera traducirla, entonces "la comunidad decidió traducirla". Si otra persona está en desacuerdo, lo plantea acá y votamos ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ya lo estuve haciendo en el chat y paso por aquí a dejar mi opinión, si no les gusta, tengo otras ;-). En primer lugar, mi +1  a la respuesta de @g3rv4, me parece adecuada y además evita la discusión entre "oficial" y "no oficial".

Con respecto a tu pregunta, la discusión de fondo me parece, pasaría por: **¿valoramos las respuestas o los autores?**. Ya se ha conversado mucho de este tema y entiendo que **valoramos las respuestas por sobre el autor**, con ese criterio, por más que resulte tentador, una respuesta de una fuente oficial y autorizada, no debería ser valorada de manera distinta a la de cualquier otro usuario, por consiguiente, entiendo, debería ser juzgada con los mismos criterios y reglas que usamos siempre.

Quitando "oficial/Autorizado" del problema, ¿Qué pasa si tenemos cualquier respuesta en otro idioma, adecuada, que funciona y responde a la pregunta?:

- le pedimos al autor que la traduzca
- no lo hace / no lo quiere hacer

¿Qué hacemos en estos casos?

1. Se reporta la respuesta y eventualmente perdemos ese contenido valioso
2. Traducimos en una nueva respuesta, esto conlleva un problema de atribución, es fácil poner un enlace a un sitio externo en otro idioma junto con la traducción, ¿pero un enlace a una respuesta que eventualmente podría terminar eliminada?
3. La opción de @g3rv4, se edita la respuesta y se agrega la traducción, si el autor no acepta la traducción, mala suerte, fin del asunto, se elimina la respuesta, si la acepta, bien para él y para el sitio. **Sin duda, a mi criterio, es lo que mejor funcionaría**

Answer (score 3):

A este sitio vienen usuarios que no saben inglés. Una respuesta en inglés no les es de utilidad.

Alegar que existe Google Translate no es excusa. ¿Por qué no lo usa él en primer lugar para traducir sus respuestas al castellano?

Quien sea el autor de la respuesta es irrelevante. El que trabaje activamente con/en el producto sólo da credibilidad a su respuesta, pero no es un permiso para saltarse las reglas.

Voto por cerrarla, como tantas otras, por no estar en castellano.

Comment: entre no tener una respuesta y tenerla en inglés, me quedo con tenerla en inglés. Además, lo de _Una respuesta en inglés no les es de utilidad._ no es cierto en el 100% de casos.

Comment: El dice que no usa Google Translator por que la calidad de la traducción haría de su respuesta, una mala respuesta. Por eso dice "if you can't use Google translate and prefer wrong answers in Spanish to the right ones in English, feel free to delete by answer:)" ... si no tiene problema en que sea borrada, menos lo tendrá en que sea traducida.

Answer (score 2):

Como punto de partida debo indicar que estoy en desacuerdo con la calificación que le da el AP al usuario del que se discute ya que no es una representante oficial como señala el título de la publicación (por favor no lo comparen con Bill Gates respecto a windows ya que no hay nivel de comparación, no es un fundador ni uno de los desarrolladores principales de la tecnologia).

Y aun asi lo fuera no tiene menos deberes que los otros usuarios, y el principal deber(regla) en SOes es que las preguntas y respuestas esten en el idioma español<sup>(1)</sup>.

Si se considera la traducción de las publicaciones de los representantes <strike>oficiales</strike> de las tecnologias entonces tengo las siguientes inquietudes:

- ¿Cuales son los requisitos para que un usuario sea calificado como representante <strike>oficial</strike>?
- ¿Se aplicaria el mismo concepto para otros idiomas distintos al inglés?
- ¿Qué sucede si nadie traduce la publicación?
- ¿Tambien se aplicara el mismo criterio para las preguntas?

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Nota al margen: alguna vez se propuso que se pueden señalar referencias a post de otro idioma y lo rechazaron porque argumentaron que los usuarios del sitio no tienen el deber de conocer ese idioma por lo que seria inservible)</sub>

---

Segun SO este lugar es una colección de preguntas y respuetas de calidad, y los sitios como SOes se crearon para la comunidad que no habla el idioma del sitio principal o sencillamente quiere obtener preguntas y respuestas en otro idioma como el españo. Del proceso de preguntar y responder preguntas de calidad se genera una consecuencia: el proceso de ayuda. Con lo anterior quiero recalcar que el objetivo principal del sitio es la calidad.

Considerando lo anterior, diferenciar entre usuarios va en contra de ese punto ya que un usuario que realiza aportaciones de calidad no implica que la siguiente aportación tambien lo sea por ello pido que la discusión tomo como enfoque a la calidad del post en vez de la calidad del usuario.  Si la comunidad considera que esa respuesta es **muy valiosa** (atención a mi enfásis)  entonces pienso que se debe seguir lo siguientes pasos:

- Podrian traducirlo
- O podrian señalarle al AP que lo traduzca,
- Si despues de un tiempo prudencial no se tradujo entonces se deberia levantar una bandera que indica que no es una respuesta por lo que deberia que sea eliminada.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar más extensamente lo de _alguna vez propuse que se pueden señalar como post de referencia al post de SOen y lo rechazaron porque argumentaron que los usuarios del sitio no tienen el deber de conocer ese idioma por lo que seria inservible_? No sé exactamente a qué te refieres

Comment: Tengo la misma duda que fedorqui...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' me refiero a esta publicación: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3643 en alli se señalo que si un usuario señala en la sección de comentarios a un post en inglés(u otro idioma) entonces sería eliminado que IMO es muy cercano a lo que se esta pidiendo.

Comment: @eyllanesc ajá, ahora entiendo. En cualquier caso, el debate allí se zanjó aceptando la respuesta no popular. Creo que sería tremendamente patoso eliminar comentarios útiles porque _en principio la gente no lo entiende_. Si quieres resolver un problema, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Mi punto va en que el OP claramente señala en uno de los comentarios: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3643/qu%c3%a9-debemos-hacer-con-las-recomendaciones-que-mandan-a-leer-una-respuesta-en-in#comment13116_3646 *Solo se pide que haya respuestas claras, **y en el idioma del sitio**.* pero ahora quiere romper su regla porque el usuario es un representante de la etiqueta(cosa que yo tambien pongo en duda)

Comment: pues yo pondría en entredicho este axioma

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Me gustaria conocer tu criterio(que sea objetivo y/o medible) para que un aporte(pregunta, respuesta o comentario) en otro idioma(como el inglés) merezca mantenerse en el sitio y/o merezca que se traduzca

Comment: Difícil pregunta, no creo que pueda haber regla general. Pero si ayuda a encontrar un camino hacia la respuesta, para mí es válido. Esto en inglés, que es un idioma bastante conocido y que la red soporta; si fuera en, qué sé yo, finlandés, tendría más reticencias. Esto en cuanto a comentarios. Una pregunta, no, pues quien busca ayuda es quien debe adaptarse a la comunidad, no al revés.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Eso es subjetivo ya que si se quiere aportar (con una preguntas y/o respuestas) en un idioma diferente ya soportado por el sitio entonces debe usar el sitio señalado para ese idioma. Para mi el aporte de una pregunta tiene el mismo peso especifico que una respuesta por lo que no veo porque dar privilegios.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Por otro lado justamente la respuesta a mi pregunta IMO es la respuesta al problema de fondo. Generalmente en este tipo de discusiones donde no existe la respuesta correcta, o al menos no es unica, yo prefiero aplicar la *navaja de ockham* y señalar que se debe eliminar esa contribución ya que no cumple con la regla del sitio que es el uso del idioma oficial.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' A diferencia de tu criterio la mia es clara y fácil de aplicar.

Comment: Pareciendome correctas el resto de opiniones, estoy de acuerdo con el razonamiento de @eyllanesc. Es fácil, sencillo y sigue un mismo criterio. Añadiría que si el usuario no quiere traducirla y se considera de utilidad, podría ser traducida por la comunidad y puesta como respuesta (si esto es posible de hacer). Para que no se pierda.

Comment: Creo que perdemos con frecuencia la perspectiva del objetivo del sitio, que no es otro que ayudar a la gente a resolver sus dudas. No sé a ti, pero a mí me resultaría bastante fastidioso pensar que he preguntado algo, no tiene respuesta y alguien dejó alguna pista (ya sea en forma de comentario o respuesta) que me puede ayudar a resolverlo... pero se me prohíbe verlo porque no cumple unas reglas. "¡Caramba!", pensaría, "esto no está bien". Que una regla sea simple no quiere decir que sea buena _per se_.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Creo que tu te estas desviando del objetivo del sitio ya que el objetivo principal es tener una colección de Q&A de calidad, lo demas es consecuencia de lo anterior

Comment: No sigo el razonamiento de tu argumento. Si alguien proporciona una pista que ayuda en el camino de resolver un problema, mantenerlo para que se traduzca contribuye más a esa colección que eliminarlo.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Si quieres traducirlo entonces es genial pero si nadie lo hace entonces tendra que eliminarse desgraciadamente ya que no cumple con las reglas del sitio que es el uso del idioma oficial, asi sea el contenido de john skeet o de un usuario con una reputación de 1.

Comment: Pero justamente lo que dice fedo es lo que esta en la pregunta. y lo que estas diciendo, es justamente lo que esta en la pregunta... Yo nunca dije y esta claro, que se dejara en ingles.. lo que si pregunte, fue como tratar la respuesta para que aportara al sitio.

Comment: @gbianchi Lo que usted señala es que es por el solo hecho de ser *"representante oficial de la herramienta"* entonces debe de tener un trato preferente y eso es lo que estoy en contra, ademas de que el titulo de *"representante oficial de la herramienta"* es subjetivo, ¿segun tu criterio yo soy un representante oficial  de Qt? Entonces seria correcto que yo publique mis respuestas en otro idioma diferente al del sitio.

Comment: ya zanjamos ese tema.. y la pregunta dice "dejarla solamente en inglés en mi parecer es un NO." o sea, yo no soy partidaria de dejarla en ingles, pero no soy quien para borrar una respuesta correcta en otro idioma que soluciona el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi 1) ¿donde se zanjo ese tema? Salvo que tenga un problema de visión y/o comprensión tu post aun señala eso, y aun el título de tu post lo resalta. 2) Ahora mi duda es: ¿Todos las respuestas que estan en otro idioma se deben traducir? 3) ¿Si esta en otro idioma diferente al ingĺés entonces tambien se debe traducir? 4) Si no todas las respuestas en otro idioma se deben traducir entonces ¿En qué casos si son válidos la traducción? ¿Hay algun criterio objetivo para tomar esa decisión? Por favor si seria tan amable de usar la misma numeración para responder

Comment: 1) tache todas las referencias a oficial en el post. quedo la del titulo, mal yo, ya te la tacho. 2) es justamente lo que estoy preguntando! 3) nunca hable de ningun idioma en particular, y es lo que estoy preguntando! 4) y esto es caso a caso.. no se puede hacer una regla general, porque puede que un caso valga la pena y otro no.. no hay una respuesta a eso...

Comment: @gbianchi Justamente porque no hay criterio claro yo planteo un criterio sencillo: Si nadie quiere traducir el post entonces debe ser eliminada

Comment: pero ya lo tradujeron! no quien hizo la respuesta... y eso es justamente lo que preguntaba yo... queres que te lo plantee de otra forma? si una respuesta en otro idioma vale la pena, debemos traducirla, o la borramos y esperamos que magicamente alguien conteste lo mismo en nuestro idioma?

Comment: @gbianchi Parece que no has entendido mi punto (o que no me hice entender) pero mi duda es ¿qué sucede con los post que no son traducidos? ¿se deben dejar sin traducción o se deben eliminar?

Comment: @gbianchi Por otro lado ¿quienes calificarian como *"alguien que parece representar a la herramienta"*?, yo estaria más cómodo si tu post elimina todo sobre "representante" y quedara como *"¿Qué se debe hacer con una respuesta en inglés que parece de calidad?"*, asi se evitaria los conceptos de "privilegiados" y de discriminación

Comment: No. no lo voy a cambiar mas. Me reportaron una respuesta, y en lugar de decidir por mi mismo, hago un estudio del caso, y lo planteo en meta. Si no te parece comodo mi estudio, perfecto. Pero lo que estoy preguntando es que deberiamos hacer. Me parece que ponerse a discutir esto, en lugar del problema de fondo, es cansador. Ademas, que, si cambio esas referencias de pronto vas a estar de acuerdo con dejarla? si fuera asi, lo hubieras aclarado en tu respuesta. Yo aca termino el tema. Si no estas de acuerdo con algo, plantealo en otra pregunta en meta.

Comment: @gbianchi Por favor toma con buenas ganas mis comentarios, mi petición es para justamente no distraernos en cosas triviales como definir que es *"alguien que parece representar a la herramienta"*

Comment: @gbianchi Si se llega al consenso de que solo se deben traducir los post de los que  "parecen ser representantes de la herramienta" entonces publicare un post para que me aclaren ese término. Y por favor no digas la frase: *Si no estas de acuerdo con algo, plantealo en otra pregunta en meta.* ya que es muy obvia y equivale a decir: "no me molestas más"

Comment: @gbianchi Si te parece cansado o estresante responder a mis cuestionamientos entonces no lo hagas, es sencillo.

Comment: Es que ya respondi a todos tus cuestionamientos. Plantee la pregunta como me parecio respecto de todas las cosas que vi. Si no te gusta mi planteamiento perfecto, estas en tu derecho de hacer lo que te parezca mejor. Pero no voy a seguir con el tema de oficial o no oficial. Ya quite todas las referencias y deje todo en potencial. no voy a cambiar toda la pregunta, porque justamente a eso apunta la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas veces me he topado con preguntas cuyas soluciones ya existen en el sitio de stackoverflow en inglés, siempre me ha parecido que para poder aportar algo **es preferible** que sea de autoría propia, sin embargo, si la respuesta en inglés esta bien formulada y es de utilidad para la persona que pregunta, considero importante escribir esa respuesta o bien, una cita al post original con una correcta traducción, ya qué así, no solo ayudaríamos al usuario que formuló la pregunta, si no que, también estaríamos enriqueciendo el sitio con respuestas en español.

Lo que no veo correcto es solo hacer referencia al post sin traducir o aportar algo esperando un merito por hacer copy-paste.

Comment: Los post que estan copiados del sitio en ingles, tienen atribucion al post original, inclusive si solo se tomo como idea (yo por lo menos lo hago asi). Aca no hubo copy paste.. es una respuesta original... solo que en otro idioma...

Comment: @gbianchi claro! me refiero cuando ni siquiera realizan la traducción, esperando que su atribución sea solo copiar la respuesta de otro post (y a veces, tampoco agregan de donde consiguieron esa respuesta).

Comment: No hay respuestas en ingles.. se borran.. y eso es justamente lo que planteo aca...

Comment: @RedSalas a que te refieres? A que alguien publica una "respuesta" del post original sin traducir? O que solo "comenta" referenciando el link?