# El comentario que coloqué sirvió como respuesta

Tags: discusión, respuesta

hace poco comenté en la pregunta de un usuario, el cual le sirvió de ayuda por que resolvió su duda. ahora bien no lo coloqué como respuesta.

Debería de poner de nuevo el comentario como respuesta para que la pregunta quede como respondida o bien se puede dejar así no mas? que pasa en estos casos? que se debería de hacer?

Comment: Referencia: [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/490581/problema-con-select2-etiqueta-fantasma).

Comment: pues no hay ningún problema, lo puedes dejar como comentario y dejar que el usuario haga su propia respuesta con tu comenario y con lo el haya invesigado. O si quieres puedes hacer una respuesta más completa

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3432/65

Answer (score 7):

Los comentarios pueden ayudar a que el OP pueda resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, pero si deseas realizar una respuesta no debes únicamente agregar un comentario, debes realizar una publicación en base a :

[**¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Esta respuesta necesita ser mejorada, puedes editar tu respuesta agregando mayor información

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes realizar una publicación cuyo objetivo sea que ayude a resolver el problema pero que también sea útil para la comunidad y usuarios que en un futuro tengan la misma problemática.

Comment: eso mismo quería saber, por eso tenia la duda, por que en realidad la respuesta es exacta para su pregunta pero gracias para la próxima ya lo se